# Better latest version or the package for rkhunter and chkrootkit?

Tags: ubuntu, security, webserver, chkrootkit, rkhunter

The `rkhunter` version of the ubuntu package is currently `1.4.0`, while the installer is version `1.4.4` 
The repo version of `chkrootkit` is `0.49`, while its installer is `0.52` 
Since security is a major concern for servers, what would be the best choice: install the latest version or my distribution's package, even if outdated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the best of both worlds by installing the latest package available from your distribution: [`rkhunter` 1.4.4](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rkhunter) and [`chkrootkit` 0.52](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chkrootkit) for Ubuntu (the packages’ dependencies are satisfiable in previous releases of Ubuntu). The safest approach is to download the packages manually, and install them with `dpkg -i` or `gdebi`. You’ll need to keep an eye on future updates to those packages manually, but then you’d have had to do that anyway if you’d used the upstream downloads.

You *could* get automatic upgrades from Ubuntu by adding the Aardvark repositories and pinning; that’s beyond the scope of this answer though.

Upgrading in both cases is quite useful as you mention, since both projects have added new security checks (in particular, Linux.Proxy.10 in `chkrootkit`).

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind to provide me with some hint on where to find information and documentation on the `Aardvark repositories`?

Comment: To find the Artful Aardvark repositories, look in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and copy the lines containing `vivid`, `xenial`, `yakkety`, or `zesty`, replacing the release name with `artful`. The Ubuntu wiki has [a page on pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) with detailed instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `older` version are to be preferred over the `latest` version as the former have been thoroughly tested by the Ubuntu team and would have little or no issues when compared to the `latest` versions of these packages.